# I created a recursion that is supposed to count amount of numbers satisfying sertan conditions, but it doesn't work for some reason

Tags: python, recursion

Here is the code:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(None)

def f(l,d,s):

    if l==12:
        return (len(d)==12 and (all(int(d[i],16)%2!=int(d[i+1],16)%2) \
            for i in range(len(d)-1)))

    if l<12 and all(d[-1]<=h for h in s):return 0

    else:

        return sum(f(l+1,d+j,s=s.replace(j,"")) for j in s if j<d[-1])

print(sum(f(1,d,"0123456789abcdef") for  d in "fedcb"))
```

I had to calculate the number of hexadecimal twelve-digit numbers in which the digits are in descending order, and even digits alternate with odd ones.

Comment: It would be simpler if you started with 'fedcba9876543210' which satisfies two of your conditions and chose which four digits to to remove from it in order for it to be twelve digits long and still satisfy the descending and alternating conditions

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Whats the expected output vs what you are gettinf.

Comment: Also provide a [mcve], i.e. make sure the code contains just one example case of your algorithm failing but stripped of everything that is not necessary to run it. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Oh, btw, your code in almost impossible to read and understand. That works for you, but it doesn't work for others or even future your. ;)

Comment: Thanks! It gives an error for operand "+":"int" and generator.

Comment: When `l==12` and `len(d)==12`, `f` returns a generator. Check that `if l==12:` case - you likely don't have the parentheses exactly how you want them.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to find a solution without recursion, using itertools.combinations

Comment: Thank you! that's such a relief!This recursion also works!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a recursive or iterative algorithm. As mentioned in comments, the restrictions are such that you need to count how many ways there are to remove 4 characters from `'fedcba9876543210'`, and because of the odd/even constraint, you need to remove two *consecutive pairs*. For instance, you could remove "ba" and "65", but not "d", "9", "4", "0" (as that violates the odd/even constraint).

For the leftmost consecutive pair we have 12 choices: "fe", "ed", "de", ..., "43", "32" (we cannot choose "21" or "10", as that leaves no choice for the second pair).

For the rightmost pair we have 12 options when we chose "fe" for the first pair, 11 when we chose "ed", ...etc.

So the total number of choices are 12 + 11 + 10 + ... + 2 + 1. This is a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF), and so we have a closed formula for the solution: 12*13/2 = 78. No need for a program.